# UITextField Should accept number only values

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have UITexfields i want that it should accept only number other shows alert that enter a numeric value.
I want that motionSicknessTextFiled should only accept number

```
NSString*dogswithMotionSickness=motionSicknessTextField.text;
NSString*valueOne=cereniaTextField.text;
NSString*valueTwo=prescriptionTextField.text;
NSString*valueThree=otherMeansTextField.text;
NSString*valueFour=overtheCounterTextField.text;
```

Comment: something like this? http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/08/uitextfield-only-allow-numeric-entry.html

Comment: Answered a [similar question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12944946/868193)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944789/allow-only-numbers-for-uitextfield-input/44178930#44178930

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In whatever UITextField you're getting these values from, you can specify the kind of keyboard you want to appear when somebody touches inside the text field.

E.G. a numeric-only keyboard.

**Like this screenshot:**

[image: numeric only keyboard will appear]

This is easily set when working with the XIB and the Interface Builder built into Xcode, but if you want to understand this programmatically, take a look at Apple's [`UITextInputTraits` protocol reference page, specifically the `keyboardType` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits) information.

To filter out punctuations, set the textfield's delegate and set up the shouldChangeCharactersInRange method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:textField.text];

    BOOL stringIsValid = [numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField];
    return stringIsValid;
}
```

Comment: Also on a side note to take decimal inputs (float) use the DecimalPad.

Comment: You should use `[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]` and not `textField.text` when creating `characterSetFromTextField` as the `text` property has not updated yet.

Comment: In xcode 7, you may find this option in the attributes inspector tab. There is an option called keyboard types.

Comment: This code is allowing the first character as alphabetic. how to fix that?

Comment: @R.Mohan did you set the keyboard type to numeric? make sure you return ‘false’ from that method for any alphabetic characters.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I set the keyboard type to Phone Pad, stringIsValid is returning YES for the first alphabetic character and NO for second or third alphabets.

Answer (score 27):

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (!string.length) 
        return YES;

    if (textField == self.tmpTextField)
    {
        NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        NSString *expression = @"^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$";
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression 
                                                                               options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                                 error:nil];
        NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:newString
                                                            options:0
                                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])];        
        if (numberOfMatches == 0)
            return NO;        
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if !string.characters.count {
        return true
    }
    do {
        if textField == self.tmpTextField {
            var newString = textField.text.replacingCharacters(inRange: range, with: string)
            var expression = "^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$"
            var regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive)
            var numberOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(inString: newString, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: newString.characters.count))
            if numberOfMatches == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error {
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This doesn't allow you to delete characters once you are done editing.

Comment: @RahulSharma In this example, you can allow deletion of characters by placing a check on the length of the `string` argument and returning `YES` if the string is empty. Something like `if (!string.length) return YES;`

Answer (score 10):

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Comment: and doesn't stop copy pasta OR hardware keyboards

Answer (score 10):

### I've implemented the snippet which has the features for textField:

1. Check the **maximum allowed** characters.
2. Check the **valid decimal** number.
3. Check only **numeric** numbers.

The code is the `UITextField` delegate method. Before you use this snippet, you must have these properties:

1. `self.maxCharacters`
2. `self.numeric` // Only **int** characters.
3. `self.decimalNumeric` // Only numbers and ".", "," (for specific locales, like Russian).

### Code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(self.numeric || self.decimalNumeric)
    {
        NSString *fulltext = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
        NSString *charactersSetString = @"0123456789";

        // For decimal keyboard, allow "dot" and "comma" characters.
        if(self.decimalNumeric) {
            charactersSetString = [charactersSetString stringByAppendingString:@".,"];
        }

        NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:charactersSetString];
        NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:fulltext];

        // If typed character is out of Set, ignore it.
        BOOL stringIsValid = [numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField];
        if(!stringIsValid) {
            return NO;
        }

        if(self.decimalNumeric)
        {
            NSString *currentText = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

            // Change the "," (appears in other locale keyboards, such as russian) key ot "."
            currentText = [currentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];

            // Check the statements of decimal value.
            if([fulltext isEqualToString:@"."]) {
                textField.text = @"0.";
                return NO;
            }

            if([fulltext rangeOfString:@".."].location != NSNotFound) {
                textField.text = [fulltext stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".." withString:@"."];
                return NO;
            }

            // If second dot is typed, ignore it.
            NSArray *dots = [fulltext componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if(dots.count > 2) {
                textField.text = currentText;
                return NO;
            }

            // If first character is zero and second character is > 0, replace first with second. 05 => 5;
            if(fulltext.length == 2) {
                if([[fulltext substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"0"] && ![fulltext isEqualToString:@"0."]) {
                    textField.text = [fulltext substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
                    return NO;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Check the max characters typed.
    NSUInteger oldLength = [textField.text length];
    NSUInteger replacementLength = [string length];
    NSUInteger rangeLength = range.length;

    NSUInteger newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;
    BOOL returnKey = [string rangeOfString: @"\n"].location != NSNotFound;

    return newLength <= _maxCharacters || returnKey;
}
```

### Demo:

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Swift 3 version of this?

Answer (score 7):

Modified Michael Dautermann's answer:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(string.length > 0)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];

        BOOL stringIsValid = [numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField];
        return stringIsValid;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**swift 4**

This allows only number input and you can also set character limitation

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  let aSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted
  let compSepByCharInSet = string.components(separatedBy: aSet)
  let numberFiltered = compSepByCharInSet.joined(separator: "")

  if string == numberFiltered {
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }
    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
    return updatedText.count <= 10
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is Swift solution:

In viewDidLoad set the delegate:

```
_yourTextField.delegate = self
```

```
let _acceptableCharacters = "0123456789."

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if (string.characters.count == 0) {
        return true
    }

    if (textField == self._yourTextField) {
        let cs = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: self._acceptableCharacters)
        let filtered = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(cs).filter {  !$0.isEmpty }
        let str = filtered.joinWithSeparator("")

        return (string != str)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: How would I restrict the UITextfield to only receive numbers and limit the amount of numbers between 6 and 8?

Answer (score 1):

this is the function which checks for the String contains Numeric value only

```
+(BOOL) checkforNumeric:(NSString*) str
{
    NSString *strMatchstring=@"\\b([0-9%_.+\\-]+)\\b"; 
    NSPredicate *textpredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", strMatchstring];

    if(![textpredicate evaluateWithObject:str])
    {
        //////NSLog(@"Invalid email address found");
        UIAlertView *objAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"please enter valid text." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Close",nil];
        [objAlert show];
        [objAlert release];
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

check it on submit button.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403622/5620628) threw some error in Swift 3, here's the working answer:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    do {
        if textField == self.numberTextField {

            let nString = textField.text as NSString?
            let newString = nString?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            let expression = "^([0-9]+)?(\\.([0-9]{1,2})?)?$"
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let numberOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: newString! as String, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: (newString?.characters.count)!))

            if numberOfMatches == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error {
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 port of the best answer here by @almas-adlibek

A bunch of configuration variables:

```
private let kMaxTextLength = 8
private let kZeroDotted = "0."
private let kZero = "0"
private let kDoubleDot = ".."
private let kDot = "."
private let kPeriod = ","
```

Now the Swift 4 converted part of the code.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    guard let oldText = textField.text, let swiftRange = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
    }

    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: swiftRange, with: string)

    var currentText =  textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

    // Change the "," (appears in other locale keyboards, such as russian) key ot "."
    currentText = currentText?.replacingOccurrences(of: kPeriod, with: kDot)

    // Check the statements of decimal value.
    if (newText == kDot) {
        textField.text = kZeroDotted;
        return false
    }

    if (newText.range(of: kDoubleDot) != nil) {
        textField.text = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: kDoubleDot, with: kDot);
        return false
    }

    // If second dot is typed, ignore it.
    let dots = newText.components(separatedBy: kDot)
    if(dots.count > 2) {
        textField.text = currentText;
        return false
    }

    // If first character is zero and second character is > 0, replace first with second. 05 => 5;
    if(newText.count == 2) {
        if(newText[0...0] == kZero && newText != kZeroDotted) {
            textField.text = newText[1...1]
            return false
        }
    }

    // Check the max characters typed.
    let oldLength = textField.text?.count ?? 0
    let replacementLength = string.count
    let rangeLength = range.length

    let newLength = oldLength - rangeLength + replacementLength;
    let returnKey = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) != nil

    return newLength <= kMaxTextLength || returnKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the answer of Michael and made it a little bit easier to implement. Just make sure that the delegate of your `UITextfield` is set to itself.

```
yourTxtField.delegate = self;
```

Furthermore copy & paste this code into your main file.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

    if (textField == yourTxtField) {
        NSCharacterSet *numbersOnly = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
        NSCharacterSet *characterSetFromTextField = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];

        BOOL stringIsValid = [numbersOnly isSupersetOfSet:characterSetFromTextField];
            return stringIsValid;
        }else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

If you want to allow the use of the spacebar just put in a blank space at the end of the `CharactersInString`, just like so:

```
@"0123456789" -> @"0123456789 "
```

### Additionally:

If you want to restrict the length of the string just replace the if-function with following:

```
if (textField == yourTxtField) {
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];
        NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= 10));

    }
```

In my case the "10" at the end represents the limit of characters.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score -1):

**Swift**

```
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {

    let numbers = "0123456789";

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textfield = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 44))
        //make some customization, if you want
        self.view.addSubview(textfield)

        textfield.delegate = self;
    }
}

extension ExampleVC: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return string.characters.count > 0 ? numbers.contains(string) : true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option of entering only numeric values into your text field is by selecting the keyboard type attribute of the corresponding textfield. Attaching the screenshot for reference.[image: Number Pad Selection]

Comment: can u share code for textfield with icon you are using.

Comment: On iPad the number pad just defaults to the normal keyboard with shift selected. The user can still shift back to alphabetic. Furthermore the user can copy-and-paste any text on any device.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the working example for **swift 4**

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    // Allow Backspace
    if string.count == 0 {
        return true
    }

    // Allow Only Valid Decimal Numbers
    if let textFieldText = textField.text   {

        let finalText = (textFieldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        if Double(finalText) != nil {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```