# Eliminate multiple decimal points in number (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, formatting

I want to limit the user input to only valid numbers and am using the following:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: " -0123456789.,\t\n").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: text)) else {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

But this does not prevent entering more than one decimal point such as "1.2.3".  Is there a simple way to prevent that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITextField Should accept number only values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734959/uitextfield-should-accept-number-only-values)

Comment: Are you trying to input currency?

Comment: Are you going to read an array of numbers from UITextView?

Comment: @pkamb: it might but it only covers it for UITxtFields, not  UITextViews...

Comment: @Leo Dabus: no, but I may be able to use that...

Comment: @Andrey Maksimkin: yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783546/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this example

```
guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: " -0123456789.,\t\n").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: text)) else {
        return false
    }
    
    var newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    newText = newText.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
    
    let strings = newText.split { character -> Bool in
        return character == "\t" || character == "\n"
    }
    
    let numbers: [Double] = strings.compactMap { Double($0) }
    
    return strings.count == numbers.count
```

Answer (score 0):

This was answered for text fields by @whyceewhite several years ago. One approach is to use the `NumberFormatter()` to determine if the value is a a valid number.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return numberFormatter.number(from: textView.text + text) != nil
    }
```

Perhaps you also want to handle the case when a user enters a decimal as the first value of a number, which will return nil when put into number formatter. You can use something as follows:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (textView.text == nil || textView.text == "") && text == "." {
            textView.text = "0"
            return true
        } else {
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            return numberFormatter.number(from: textView.text + text) != nil
        }
    }
```

Which will check if the text field text is nil or empty and that the value to be inserted is a `.`, add a leading zero and then add the decimal.